# .Net Library to parse PO files

Tags: c#, .net, po

I wanted to create a translator for PO files but I thought that it's better to ask whether there is a library for .Net to parse .PO files or not.

Thanks.

Comment: I have been looking for a gettext lib for .NET too, but I was unable to find one. I have written a .po parser in php (shiver) before, it's not so hard to write one from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

The question is rather old so my answer is mainly for those who are looking for a PO parser .NET library nowadays.

I implemented a lightweight, fully-managed, .NET Standard-compatible library which is able to parse and generate PO files. Comments and plural translations are supported, as well. The library is free and open-source (released under the MIT license).

First you need to install the NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Karambolo.PO.Compact
```

Then to parse a PO file, you just need a few lines as follows:

```
var parser = new POParser();

POParseResult result;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("sample.po", Encoding.UTF8))
    result = parser.Parse(reader);

if (result.Success)
{
    POCatalog catalog = result.Catalog;
    // process the parsed data...
}
else
{
    IDiagnostics diagnostics = result.Diagnostics;
    // examine diagnostics, display an error, etc...
}
```

For further details visit the [project page](https://github.com/adams85/po).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Mono.Unix**

http://www.mono-project.com/I18N_with_Mono.Unix

Comment: I skimmed the tutorial but it seems that it is used to make .PO files from the C# code and use .PO files to translate the software. I want to write a translator software for PO files (like POEdit). Does it have the ability to do so?

Comment: The Mono.Unix package is a wrapper around the C-libs.